# MvcHtmlString.Create() vs new MvcHtmlString()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvchtmlstring

I see two common ways of creating an `MvcHtmlString`.

```
var htmlStr = MvcHtmlString.Create(str);
```

and

```
var htmlStr = new MvcHtmlString(str);
```

Is there any difference between the two?

Can I use them both interchangeably?

Is there every any reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the actual code according to the JetBrains (R#) decompiler:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Create(string value)
{
  return new MvcHtmlString(value);
}
```

So, I think you can be pretty certain there's no difference. I have been consistently using `Create` thinking there might one day be other static factory methods, and it would be more consistent to always use them, but so far, that hasn't happened.

Comment: Didn't even think to look... what a tool - thank you :)